# Error al conectar a una base de datos SQL de Azure desde una aplicacion Vb.NET Winforms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows-forms, azure-sql

Tengo una aplicación hecha en visual studio 2015 con winforms y visual basic la cual funciona con una base de datos en un servidor SQL Server 2008 R2 que se ubica dentro de la misma red local de los clientes.

actualmente deseo migrar la base de datos para que este en la nube, en Azure propiamente. Ya genere la base de datos sin problema y mis lineas de conexion en la aplicacion fueron actualizadas apuntando a Azure.

sin embargo al ejecutar la aplicacion me manda un error que mi ip publica de donde trato de conectarme no tiene permisos para conectarse y que revise la configuracion de firewall de azure para agregarla. Despues de agregarla en Azure puedo abrir la aplicacion sin problemas.

Mi pregunta es ¿Existe alguna forma que pueda tener conexion a la base de Azure sin importar de que ip publica me estoy conectando? esto ya que los clientes no cuentan con una ip publica fija y es tedioso tener que agregar la nueva ip publica cada que cambia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr con una regla en el firewall de la BD.

En vez de asignar una ip fija, asigna desde la 0.0.0.0 a la 255.255.255.255 y listo.

[image: Así se vería la configuración]

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, funciono a la perfeccion.

Comment: Por nada, para eso estamos Mauricio